# How to acces database in heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

So I have created a website with Flask and uploaded it to heroku.
The website has a database which is called test.db
In cmd i did

```
heroku vim -a my-app;
```

so now when I do dir, I get all my files, and test.db too. But how to open test.db, i tried open or read test.db. None of those seem to work. Do you know a command to open this database file?

Comment: Have you tried going through the documentation of heroku? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Copy it via `heroku ps:copy filename` to local machine. Open it on local machine as usual.

Though in general you shouldn't rely on a database that is written to file system because on Heroku your files will be wiped once every day.